# Error when uploading App

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I'm trying to update my application but it is not working. The developer console is showing an error:

```
Failed to run aapt dump badging:
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
```

I've searched for solutions but couldn't find any. 
Any idea what I could do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [aapt dump badging fails "dump failed because assets could not be loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653704/aapt-dump-badging-fails-dump-failed-because-assets-could-not-be-loaded)