# aapt dump badging fails "dump failed because assets could not be loaded"

Tags: android, apk, aapt

When I run the **aapt dump badging** on my **apk** I get the below error

```
W/asset   (17217): Asset path Users/username/Downloads/appname.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
```

I couldn't find why it happens.
I'm using iMac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have faced this problem in my case it was missing of the **(.)dot** in following terminal command

```
./aapt dump badging /Users/username/Documents/Android/Release/PROD/appname.apk
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you give me all the steps that you do for aapt dump badging

Comment: @NagaR - I am using ADT.so first I do a CD to aapt tool inside it using Terminal `cd /Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2` then use the command I mentioned to run the dump badging that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I come this issue with

```
sudo -u www /usr/share/aapt/aapt d badging /home/roofe/200.apk
getFileType got errno=13 on '/home/roofe/200.apk'
getFileType got errno=13 on '/home/roofe/200.apk'
W/asset   ( 1315): Asset path /home/roofe/200.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=0).
ERROR: dump failed because assets could not be loaded
```

But when I use `sudo /usr/share/aapt/aapt d badging /home/roofe/200.apk`, it works well. So I realise it's caused by permission.

Then I move the file to `/data/www` where the full path have the mode `www:www`, and it works.